# Weka CSVloader - error (wrong number of value. Read)

Tags: java, weka

im trying to convert CSV to ARFF by using weka. But it pop out those error message.

```
weka.core.converters.CSVLoaderfailed to lead <my file>
Reason:
wrong number of values. Read 7, expected 9, read Token[EOL], line 26
```

i have trying to replace `" ' , %` those special characters but also remain the same.

Any idea?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1__u9SGOxd-ShU9Eei3tDjZ9s1MxzKEKZ 
the file of the link

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer:

The line breaks inside values are the problem. Replace them with something else, e.g., spaces.

## Long answer:

The problem is that your values contain line breaks (`\n` or such) and that the CSVLoader from Weka can't handle it. Line 26 is the first line in your file that contains such a line break, but the CSVLoader thinks the row ends there after only 7 fields are read.

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.java):

```
private void initTokenizer(StreamTokenizer tokenizer) {
  tokenizer.resetSyntax();
  tokenizer.whitespaceChars(0, (' ' - 1));
  tokenizer.wordChars(' ', '\u00FF');
  tokenizer.whitespaceChars(m_FieldSeparator.charAt(0),
    m_FieldSeparator.charAt(0));
  // tokenizer.commentChar('%');

  String[] parts = m_Enclosures.split(",");
  for (String e : parts) {
    if (e.length() > 1 || e.length() == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Enclosures can only be single characters");
    }
    tokenizer.quoteChar(e.charAt(0));
  }

  tokenizer.eolIsSignificant(true);    // <--- This line is important
}
```

The last line there basically says that the tokenizer should treat an end of line (EOL) as special character (see the [API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#eolIsSignificant(boolean))):

> If the flag is false, end-of-line characters are treated as white space and serve only to separate tokens.

The `getInstance` method of the CSVLoader contains this logic (summarized):

```
private String getInstance(StreamTokenizer tokenizer) throws IOException {  

    // [...]

    boolean first = true;
    boolean wasSep;
    m_current.clear();

    int i = 0;
    while (tokenizer.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL
      && tokenizer.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {

      // Get next token
      if (!first) {
        StreamTokenizerUtils.getToken(tokenizer);
      }

      if (tokenizer.ttype == m_FieldSeparator.charAt(0)
        || tokenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) {
        m_current.add("?");
        wasSep = true;
      } else {
        // Parsing values
        // [...]
      }

      if (!wasSep) {
        StreamTokenizerUtils.getToken(tokenizer);
      }
      first = false;
      i++;
    }

    // check number of values read
    if (m_current.size() != m_structure.numAttributes()) {
      for (Object o : m_current) {
        System.out.print(o.toString() + "|||");
      }
      System.out.println();
      StreamTokenizerUtils.errms(tokenizer, "wrong number of values. Read "
        + m_current.size() + ", expected " + m_structure.numAttributes());

    }
  // [...]
}
```

So, not matter if the line break is inside quotes, the tokenizer will always treat it as `StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL`, which ends reading a record and thus you end up with less fields than expected.